Compiler run failed
So a bit of a N00b problem,

Error (6275): Source "/root/solidity-course/src/SimpleStorage.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "/root/solidity-course".
ParserError: Source "/root/solidity-course/src/SimpleStorage.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "/root/solidity-course".
--> script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol:6:1:

Please share your directory structure. What's inside your solidity-course folder? You can use this command in terminal ls /root/solidity-course.

If you didn't change the default folder structure of your Foundry project,
import {SimpleStorage} from "src/SimpleStorage.sol"

should be the right path.
